# OnsenUI - ion-navicon not displaying the icon

Tags: html, css, angularjs, onsen-ui

Herewhat I tried. I have given this tag inside span. But, it is not displaying the icon in navigation bar.

```
 <i class="ion-navicon" style="font-size:32px; vertical-align:-6px;"></i>
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="my-app">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="onsenui.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="onsen-css-components.css"/>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="onsenui.js"></script>
    <script>
     ons.bootstrap();
    </script>
    <style>
.navigation-bar {
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 17px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-spacing: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  line-height: normal;
  cursor: default;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  height: 44px;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  color: #1f1f21;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-weight: 400;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: visible;
}
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi) {
  .navigation-bar {
    border-bottom: none;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 1px;
    background-size: 100% 1px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #ddd, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%);
  }
}
.navigation-bar__line-height {
  line-height: 44px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
}
.navigation-bar__bg {
  background: #f8f8f8;
}
.navigation-bar__item,
.navigation-bar__left,
.navigation-bar__right,
.navigation-bar__center {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  line-height: normal;
  height: 44px;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: visible;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: left;
}
.navigation-bar__left {
  max-width: 50%;
  width: 27%;
  text-align: left;
}
.navigation-bar__right {
  max-width: 50%;
  width: 27%;
  text-align: right;
}
.navigation-bar__center {
  width: 46%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 44px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.navigation-bar__title {
  line-height: 44px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #1f1f21;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: visible;
}
.navigation-bar__center:first-child:last-child {
  width: 100%;
}

.toolbar-button,
.toolbar-button--outline,
.toolbar-button--quiet {
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #1284ff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px none;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 17px;
  -webkit-transition: none;
  -moz-transition: none;
  -o-transition: none;
  transition: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.toolbar-button:active,
.toolbar-button--outline:active,
.toolbar-button--quiet:active {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  -webkit-transition: none;
  -moz-transition: none;
  -o-transition: none;
  transition: none;
  opacity: 0.2;
}
.toolbar-button:disabled {
  opacity: 0.3;
  cursor: default;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.toolbar-button:focus,
.toolbar-button--outline:focus,
.toolbar-button--quiet:focus {
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-transition: none;
  -moz-transition: none;
  -o-transition: none;
  transition: none;
}
.toolbar-button:hover,
.toolbar-button--outline:hover,
.toolbar-button--quiet:hover {
  -webkit-transition: none;
  -moz-transition: none;
  -o-transition: none;
  transition: none;
}
.toolbar-button--outline {
  border: 1px solid #1284ff;
  margin: auto 8px;
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-right: 6px;
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="AppController">

        <!-- Page content -->

<div class="navigation-bar navigation-bar--transparent">
  <div class="navigation-bar__left">
    <span class="toolbar-button--quiet navigation-bar__line-height">
      <i class="ion-navicon" style="font-size:32px; vertical-align:-6px;"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="navigation-bar__center">
    Navigation Bar
  </div>
  <div class="navigation-bar__right">
    <span class="toolbar-button--quiet navigation-bar__line-height">Label</span>
  </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OnsenUI is using the [Ionicons](http://ionicons.com/). Therefore, in order for it to display, you need to add `ionicons.css` file into your project. There are two ways to do it:

1. Include the file locally. Go [here](http://ionicons.com/). Then, click `Download` button. Extract the file and add the `ionicons.css` file into your project. Make sure you follow this folder arrangement in ur project as below: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ionicons/css/ionicons.css">`. Otherwise, the icon still won't be shown.
2. Include the file automatically with CDN url. Add this link in ur html header:
        `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/1.5.2/css/ionicons.min.css">`

Note: I tested and the current CDN url on the website appears to be not working. Therefore, for now please add the file manually as shown in step 1.
I also notify the OnsenUI team about this. They said they will update the website and inform the users about this requirement.

Comment: It depends how you have integrated OnsenUI into your project. If you use *bower*, you'll automatically get also ionicons _and_ font awesome into you'r project. While this is convenient at a first glance, it's actually not the best because you'll get outdated versions of these two libraries.

At time of writing this comment you receive font awesome version 4.1.0 (recent is 4.4.0) and ionicons 2.0.0 (recent 2.0.1). The Onsen UI team should really consider to add a dependency to the bower configuration instead of bringing old stuff. It's easy and IMHO in this non-critical.

Answer (score 2):

Actually onsen ui allow you to use both ionicons and awesome font icons. As long as you include the essential onsens js and css, you could use them... (see their CodePen samples) but of course you could also manually add them as previous answer suggested. I didn't have to when working on my app.

Check the documentation here: `http://onsenui.io/guide/overview.html#UsingIcons`

Using Font Awesome
If the value of icon attribute starts with fa-, appropriate Font Awesome icon is used. The list of available icons can be found on the Font Awesome Website. If icon attribute has no prefix, Font Awesome collection will be used.

```
<ons-icon icon="fa-angle-left"></ons-icon>
```

or

```
<i class="fa-angle-left"></i> (as their site suggested) it works too!!
```

Using Ionicons
If the value of icon attribute starts with ion-, appropriate Ionicons icon is used. The list of available icons can be found on the Ionicons Website.

```
<ons-icon icon="ion-chevron-left"></ons-icon>
```

To find out those values to use, just go to their website:

```
http://ionicons.com/ 
http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you please look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27816145/jquery-vertical-tabs-not-working-in-onsenui

Comment: Your question is no longer existed. Let me know if you have other questions.